# SQL Select with joins across two databases. Confusing :-s

Tags: sql

If anyone could help me join these two selects together to create one mega statement that would be awesome!!

--running against quotingSystem database

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT (varchar, Quote.QuoteID) AS QuoteID, Quote.FirstName, 
    Quote.LastName, Quote.ProductSKU, Quote.ProductID, Quote.Quantity, 
    Quote.CreationDate, 
    CONVERT (CHAR(8), Quote.CreationTime, 8) AS CreationTime, 
    Quote.CompanyName, 
    IncommingQuoteStatus.StatusDesc, Quote.LockedDateTime, 
    Users.FirstName + ' ' + Users.LastName AS UserName 
FROM 
    Quote 
INNER JOIN 
    IncommingQuoteStatus ON IncommingQuoteStatus.StatusID = Quote.Status 
INNER JOIN 
    Users ON Quote.LockedUserID = Users.UserID 
WHERE 
    (Quote.Status > 2 AND Quote.Status < 6) 
ORDER BY 
    QuoteID DESC
```

-- running on quoting system database but also pulling in values from another database CBretailDB

```
select 
     D2.stock AS CurrentStock
from 
     dbo.Quote as D1 
inner join 
     CBretailDB.dbo.products AS D2 ON D1.ProductID = D2.idProduct
```

the `Quote.ProductID` on the first statement needs to join on the `D2.idProduct` from second statement to pull the `CurrentStock` value

I think that makes sense!

Many thanks

Comment: Thanks to Klaus and Mark for making my question beautiful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT (varchar, Quote.QuoteID) AS QuoteID, Quote.FirstName, Quote.LastName, 
Quote.ProductSKU, Quote.Quantity, Quote.CreationDate, CONVERT (CHAR(8), 
Quote.CreationTime, 8) AS CreationTime, Quote.CompanyName, 
IncommingQuoteStatus.StatusDesc, Quote.LockedDateTime, Users.FirstName + ' ' + 
Users.LastName AS UserName, D2.stock FROM Quote INNER JOIN IncommingQuoteStatus ON 
IncommingQuoteStatus.StatusID = Quote.Status INNER JOIN Users ON Quote.LockedUserID = 
Users.UserID 
INNER JOIN CBretailDB.dbo.products AS D2 ON Quote.ProductID = D2.idProduct
WHERE (Quote.Status > 2 AND Quote.Status < 6) ORDER BY QuoteID DESC
```